# How can I use Object.assign(this,{foo,bar}) and have VSCode Intellisense autocomplete this.foo?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsdoc

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor({foo,bar}) {
    Object.assign(this,{foo,bar})
  }
}
```

I want to make it so when I type `this.f` VSCode autocompletes `this.foo`. I know if I do this

```
class MyClass {
  constructor({foo,bar}) {
    this.foo = foo
    this.bar = bar
  }
}
```

it will give me what I want, but I would prefer to use `Object.assign()`. I'm having trouble figuring out the right JSDoc or whatever to use. Adding `@prop {String} foo` or something at the top of the class doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 7):

As of VS Code 1.18, we don't support intellisense for `Object.assign(this)`. This bug is being tracked [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16163)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the link! I'll subscribe to that issue. Regardless of `Object.assign()`, do you know of any way using JSDoc to get intellisense to autocomplete an arbitrary class property that isn't defined in the ways intellisense currently recognizes?

Comment: There's not a great story currently. [We don't yet support `@property`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15715) which would be best solution.

Comment: Thanks; that's good to know. I'll subscribe to that issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since VSC uses TypeScript under the hood to provide IntelliSense, there is a workaround with some trade-offs: using `@this` [JSDoc tag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#this) if you don't mind some duplication.

You have to define the type as an intersection of the constructor type and the assigned object type for the constructor and/or any field defined on the class you want additional `this` IntelliSense for:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {{
 *   foo: string;
 *   bar: string;
 * }} MyAdditions
 */

class MyClass {
    /**
     * @param {MyAdditions} options
     * @this {MyClass & MyAdditions}
     */
    constructor({ foo, bar }) {
        Object.assign(this, { foo, bar });

        // all ok
        this.foo;
        this.bar;
    }

    /**
     * @this {MyClass & MyAdditions}
     */
    doSomethingWithMyAdditions() {
        const { foo, bar } = this; // all ok too
        console.log(`${foo}${bar}`);
    }
}
```

The caveat, however, is referring to the properties from class instances. Unfortunately, overriding `this` type of a constructor does not change its return type (given the example above, the return type is still `MyClass`), so this is still illegal:

```js
const c = new MyClass({ foo: "bar", bar: "foo" });
c.foo; //Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'MyClass'
c.bar; //Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'MyClass'
```

A cookie smart enough to try to add a `@returns` tag to the constructor will be greeted with a TS1903 error "Type annotation cannot appear on a constructor declaration". Using `@type` annotation (i.e. `@type {new () => MyClass & MyAdditions}`) as an alternative simply results in a no-op.

That said, nothing stops you from casting an instance type (after all, instantiation should not happen too often) with the `@type` annotation (note the parenthesis around the `new`):

```js
const d = /** @type {MyClass & MyAdditions} */ (new MyClass({ foo: "bar", bar: "foo" }));
d.foo; // ok now
d.bar; // ok now
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&filetype=js#code/PQKhCgAIUgBAXAngBwKYBNUDNIG9dQySRYD2pAXJAM7wBOAlgHYDmA3IcZAEYCGdVWo1YdokAL7jIAWUQBBdOgbwGpJtULBw4AMYAbXtWozEAYQNG8ULqAhdiMWMn68AtnlkKlKtdSmlkH3VrLkd4AAsGY1xZc0NjADITL2VVdXEQhy17HV96AFcdeFI6AApcEnIAGh5+CQBKK3t7AHluACtUIoA6eIYWJlKIqJqKslIavjoGjkz7YGBIXj09SFIAazmuYepu8dFm4h3uqYPiDMzbObDI6NiLROTFVN8M5pBsrnRSAGVSV1Qw1YAHVlOFPM8gtRSo0CIdiLl1PA8JUJrVplIALyQHZsSALJYrNbrHHkLYI3ykPSobp6UgsUoAAwAJLhxuJWVNxIz6mcJOALojaJAdJBsUxUAB3ExxIzlVFUABEU0Vk34SvGipmuj25DxCwACnQAqg6EhIABycYWyDfVDGJikZGoAAeUWRahxKFQlvu8QtOtO+OARpNZsQlqmNrtDqdkFd7rWTC9aF9ZgeAd0eVtYvxYDgSFTMXT8UgSQh3jSfmgi1KEulfrlY3ISpVaoEkEVmoavPA6F1pH1iw2kEdkr7J34Q+Jo9I46AA)

In any case, this is only a workaround, and the [original issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26792) is still in the backlog.